# Grid-row specified for rows 2/5, but not working as expected and fills out only 1 row

Tags: css, gridview

In the following example I wanted to stretch box 4 into rows 2-3-4.
I used the option "grid-row: 2/5;", but it is not working as expected and fills out only one row: 2/3.

Code here:

```
<style>
    .wrapper {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 2fr 1fr;
        grid-gap: 1em;
        grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
    }
    .wrapper > div {
        background-color: #ddd;
        padding: 1em;
        border: black 1px solid
    }

    .box1 {
        grid-column: 1/5;
    }
    .box3 {
        grid-column: 2/4;
        grid-row: 2/3
    }
    .box2 {
        grid-row: 2/6;
    };
    .box4 {
        grid-row: 2/5;
        grid-column: 4/5;
    }
    .box7 {
        grid-row: 4/5;
        grid-column: 2/4;
    }
    .box8 {
        grid-row: 5/6;
        grid-column: 2/5;
    }
</style>
```

And Body here:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class='box1'>1</div>
    <div class='box2'>2</div>
    <div class='box3'>3</div>
    <div class='box4'>4</div>
    <div class='box5'>5</div>
    <div class='box6'>6</div>
    <div class='box7'>7</div>
    <div class='box8'>8</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the issue was: The semicolon ';' after .box2 block causes the problem.